# C++ undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, xcode

I know there are many questions with the same issue but I did not find anything close to my problem.

I am using Xcode for a C++ project and I get the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Decrypt::printEncryptedString()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "Decrypt::Decrypt()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My main file is the folowing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Decrypt.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Decrypt decryption = Decrypt();
    decryption.printEncryptedString();
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

My header:

```
#ifndef Decrypt_hpp
#define Decrypt_hpp

#include <stdio.h>

#endif /* Decrypt_hpp */
#include <string>

class Decrypt{
    std::string toDecrypt;
    std::string encrypted;

    int keyLength; // key between 2 and 12
public:
    Decrypt();
    void printEncryptedString();

};
```

and the .cpp file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

class Decrypt{
    std::string toDecrypt;
    std::string encrypted;

    int keyLength;

public:
    Decrypt(){
        int i;
        unsigned char ch;
        FILE *fpIn;
        fpIn = fopen("ctext.txt", "r");

        i=0;
        while (fscanf(fpIn, "%c", &ch) != EOF) {
            /* avoid encrypting newline characters */
            /* In a "real-world" implementation of the Vigenere cipher,
             every ASCII character in the plaintext would be encrypted.
             However, I want to avoid encrypting newlines here because
             it makes recovering the plaintext slightly more difficult... */
            /* ...and my goal is not to create "production-quality" code =) */
            if (ch!='\n') {
                i++;
                encrypted += ch;

            }
        }

        fclose(fpIn);
    }
    //void CalculateKeyLength(){}

    void printEncryptedString(){
        std::cout << encrypted << '\n';
    }

};
```

I do not understand what causes the errors. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Are you sure if source file with Decrypt implementations is compiled too ? BTW, #endif needs to be at the end of the header file.

Comment: That's not the way to do it. You declare an entirely new class `Decrypt` in the cpp file. You should `#include` the header and then just implement the member functions.

Comment: Oh, and the `#endif` for the include guard should be at the end of the file, not in the middle.

Comment: @Bo Persson Thanks..Sorry for the dumb question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allowed to define the `Decrypt` class multiple times in your project (otherwise inclusion of header files would be a problem!), *but* each definition must be exactly the same.

You have two definitions that are different from each other. One has inline definitions of its member functions; the other does not.

This has *undefined behaviour* and, here, that is apparently manifesting as your compiler ignoring the definition in the `.cpp`, which it'll "see" second. That second definition contains your member function definitions, so they're not making it into the build.

In your `.cpp` file, define your member functions individually like this:

```
Decrypt::Decrypt()
{
    int i;
    unsigned char ch;
    FILE *fpIn;
    fpIn = fopen("ctext.txt", "r");

    i=0;
    while (fscanf(fpIn, "%c", &ch) != EOF) {
        /* avoid encrypting newline characters */
        /* In a "real-world" implementation of the Vigenere cipher,
         every ASCII character in the plaintext would be encrypted.
         However, I want to avoid encrypting newlines here because
         it makes recovering the plaintext slightly more difficult... */
        /* ...and my goal is not to create "production-quality" code =) */
        if (ch!='\n') {
            i++;
            encrypted += ch;

        }
    }

    fclose(fpIn);
}

void Decrypt::printEncryptedString()
{
    std::cout << encrypted << '\n';
}
```

Just like that. Not inside a second `class` definition.

The chapter on member functions in your C++ book will explain all this to you, and more.

Also note that your header guard in `Decrypt.hpp` has been "closed" in the middle of the file rather than at the end, which cannot be intentional?

Comment: The problem was there also without inline. The solution, was already given me by the comment in my question. Ill liked your answer anyway

Comment: @Rorschach: Yes, I know: my suggestion is the same as the one given in Bo's comment. However, answers should not be given as comments, but as _answers_, and this one provides a lot more detail for you, not to mention an _explanation_ of what's actually going on.

Answer (score -1):

Your definition of `Decrypt::printEncryptedString()` is different than your declaration. In your declaration, it is named `void Decrypt::printEncryptedString` and your definition defines the function `inline void Decrypt::printEncryptedString`. If you remove the `inline` keyword from your function definition, it should compile.

Comment: It already does compile, and I'm afraid it looks like the `inline` was a mistake as it has been removed from the code. Regardless, the function would be implicitly `inline` anyway in the second definition so, though I haven't checked, I think this would have been legal. More so than it is now, come to think of it. Ignoring the fact that it's all UB, of course...